# Ancestor query in transaction (objectify) returns data "frozen in time"

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Straight to example:

```
@Entity
public class Parentt {
    @Id
    String id;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Parent 
    Ref<Parentt> parenttRef;
    @Id
    String id;
}

public void test() {
final Parentt parentt = new Parentt();
        ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {
            @Override
            public void vrun() {

                parentt.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                ofy().save().entity(parentt).now();
                Child child = new Child();
                child.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                child.setParentt(parentt.getId());
                ofy().save().entity(child).now();

                LOG.info("query result size: " + ofy().load().type(Child.class).ancestor(parentt).list().size());
                ofy().flush();
                LOG.info("query result size: " + ofy().load().type(Child.class).ancestor(parentt).list().size());

            }
        });

        LOG.info("query result size(outside of transaction): " + ofy().load().type(Child.class).ancestor(parentt).list().size());
}
```

The result generated by the code inside the test() method:

```
query result size: 0

query result size: 0

query result size(outside of transaction): 1
```

I have found in Objectify documentation:

> There are some quirks at the low-level API: For example, get()s and
>   query()s will see the datastore "frozen in time" and will not reflect
>   updates even within the transaction. Objectify hides this behavior
>   from you; subsequent fetches will see the same data seen (or updated)
>   previously. Note that since queries are always run inside of GAE,
>   indexes (ie, filtering operations) always appear to be frozen in time
>   - Objectify can't hide this.

Does the ancestor query is based on an index internally and that is the reason why the query returns no results inside of a transaction (there is no other filtering than the parent here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries are inherently based on an index - they are served by a roundtrip to GAE. Thus GAE's behavior defines the return values. There's really nothing else that Objectify can do here.

Comment: what does it mean that "Objectify hides this behavior from you". Prior to seeing this test case from gswierczynski, I thought "hides" meant Objectify would override this quirk. In other words, when I read "Objectify hides this behavior" I thought gswierczynski's test case would have output size of 1 for all three log statement. So could you clarify what "hides" means? Thank you!

Comment: If you perform a get-by-key operation, you'll get the object out of the session - so behavior will be somewhat different from the "frozen" description in the low level API. Objectify is not a query engine; it does not have special access to indexes, so when you run a query you get back what GAE gives you. You'll still get back the object in the session if the query returns that value, though.